# Android. WebView. Horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, прокрутка, horizontalscrollview

Есть [страница](http://www.mpt.ru/education/aud_fond/aud_1ch.htm), у нее почем зря большой горизонтальный скрол. При загрузке этой страницы в WebView он естественно не пропадает. Можно ли ограничить в WebView горизонтальный скрол? Или отображать только часть станицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде страницы есть такой участок:

```
<td class="xl10325204">ь ь<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;...очень много...&nbsp;</span></td>
```

Можете взять страницу, удалить этот участок и скормить в `WebView`. Будет только таблица без лишнего скролла.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на каждый день недели есть такая страница и на всех есть этот, с позволения сказать, баг. Кроме "ь ь" и моря "&nbsp;" ничего общего. Порой даже номер строки отличается. Поэтому я хотел что-то сделать со скролом, а не самой страницей.

Comment: @Viewed   Jsoup в помощь вам :)